# Why does the official docker image for mongo not use XFS, and then warn about not using it?

Tags: docker, mongodb, xfs

According to the official docs, MongoDB with WiredTiger is supposed to be run on Linux with the XFS filesystem. Yet, the official docker image for mongo uses ext4, which means that we get a warning whenever we boot up a container:

```
Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine. See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem"
```

So why is it that the official docker image does not use XFS? Is this a concern of negligible importance?

Comment: Because docker images aren't VMs. They don't use their own filesystem but instead the host's FS.

Comment: @AlexD Really? When I run the mongo container on my mac (which uses APFS), the  filesystem within the (Ubuntu) container reads as ext4

Comment: Docker on Mac launches containers within a virtual machine which runs Linux.

Comment: @AlexD OK, thanks for the info

Comment: That is an informational message that if you are using containers in this and other typical configurations, the performance could be twice as fast when using xfs.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The full answer.

A docker image doesn't have a file system. A docker image is a bunch of `tar` files each representing a layer plus some JSON files with the image metadata. When a docker image is pulled into a host these files are unpacked into the host file system, usually under `/var/lib/docker`. When a docker container starts, these layers are mounted inside the container using OverlayFS, a union FS which allows combining different filesystem sub-directories with different image layers into a single virtual filesystem. If there are volumes then they are bind-mounted and within a container, you would see them as the original filesystem that the host has `/var/lib/docker` on (unless `tmpfs` is used).

Consequentially, it is outside of the control of the image authors which FS it is going to run on. If you want to use a specific filesystem like `XFS` from within the container then either run it on a system which uses this FS for `/var/lib/docker` or bind-mount a separate FS into the container. Won't work on Mac or Windows as Docker Desktop on these systems uses an internal VM to run containers and I don't think it is possible to modify this VM's FS.